# Let $f$ be a continuous function such that $f((a,b))\subset [a,b]$ show that there exists $c \in [a,b]$ such that $f(c)=c$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, fixed-points

Let $f$ be a continuous function on the interval $(a,b)$ such that $$f((a,b))\subset [a,b].$$ Show that, there exists $c \in [a,b]$ such that $f(c)=c$.

I thought about using the Intermediate Value Theorem in the function
$$\psi(x)=f(x)-x,\: \forall \: x\in [a,b],$$ but I stopped at the problem of $ f $ not being set to $ a $ and $ b $. I don't know if it's a problem to work around or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statement is not true, here are some counterexamples for functions $ f:(a, b) \to [a, b]$ without fixed point:

- $f(x) = a$,
- $f(x) = a + \frac 12 (x-a)$,
- $f(x) = a +  \frac{(x-a)^2}{b-a}$.

If $f$ has no fixed point in $(a, b)$ then either
$$
a \le f(x) < x \quad \text{ for all } x \in (a, b)
$$ or
$$
 x < f(x) \le b \quad \text{ for all } x \in (a, b) \, .
$$
so that 
$$
 \lim_{x\to a}f(x) = a \quad \text{ or } \quad \lim_{x\to b}f(x) = b \, .
$$

It follows that $f$ has a fixed point, or $f$ can be continuously extended to (at least) one of the boundary points of the interval, and the extended function has a fixed point.